# Get google result from my app

Tags: javascript, html

When I enter in google search bar with the following search term, I get a list of items that matches g300s from the site umart.com.au

> site:umart.com.au g300s

And the first result comes back from the browser is

> http://www.umart.com.au/umart1/pro/Products-details.phtml?id=10&id2=501&bid=12&sid=241593

I want to be able to do the exact same thing with my app where the user can type in the search term and my app will return the url of the first search result.

However, I am not sure how this can be achieved as when I view page source from the returned result, I do not see a list of links. All I see is a bunch of javascript code.

In other words, if I do an ajax request on

> https://www.google.com.au/#safe=off&q=site:umart.com.au+g300s

I will not get a list of matches that I would expect.

Is there a way to get the first search result from google through some way?

Comment: I think this is the anti-crawler policy of google

Comment: Use Google's API.  That's what its for.  https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: If I am not wrong, the google's search api is not designed to do this task. it is designed to search data inside a particular site rather than gives me a list of data returned from google

Comment: No, it can be used to search the entire web.  Also, they way you're trying to do it is forbidden by their Terms of Service.